# return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(3)

Tags: python, django, django-models, error-handling

This happens after python manage.py makemirgations which works okay. Then when I run python manage.py migrate I get this error. I've tried changing the max_length in the charfield, same error. I tried deleting and changing the default value and null and run makemigrations which states no change detected.

```
class Casting_Role(models.Model):
name = models.TextField()
min_age = models.IntegerField(default='18', blank=False)
max_age = models.IntegerField(default='100', blank=False)
ETHNICITIES = (
    ('BA', 'Black / African Descent'),
    ('WC', 'White / European Descent'),
    ('A', 'Asian'),
    ('H', 'Hispanic'),
    ('I', 'Indian'),
    ('ME', 'Middle Eastern'),
    ('PI', 'Pacific Islander'),
    ('EA', 'Ethnically Ambiguous'),
    ('IP', 'Indigenous People'),
    ('OP', 'Open'),
)
ethinicity = models.CharField(
    max_length=30, choices=ETHNICITIES, default='Open')
```

Comment: first of all, `Models` in django are written in `PascalCase`, as they are python classes.

Comment: is that something you seen in my code?

Comment: Yes, write `CastingRole` instead. Do you deleted any of `migration` files?

Comment: Any advice on the error? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are two different wrong usages in your code. I think by changing them, your problem will be fixed:

**1)** In your `Casting_Role` default value should be changed:

```
ethinicity = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=ETHNICITIES, default='OP')
```

because it is the default key in your choices, and `Open` is the value of that key.

**2)** Please make sure that your model is sync with your database. Based on this error your field length is 3 (i.e. `max_length=3` in `Casting_Role` table. If you're sure that this error is coming from this model). So maybe running `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands solve this problem part. If your data/migration files are not important for you, you can simply drop your database, delete your migration files and then run migration commands again.

Do part **2**, if you want to make sure that your database is in sync with your models. Because it seems they are not at the moment.

Comment: this did not work for me. I changed the max_length to 30 but the error is still saying "value too long for the type character varying(3). I also tried to change the character varying number manually in postgres to 30 but it states the same error. How do I by pass the deleting database option. I dont want to have to delete and start fresh everytime. Seems like the database is not synch for this model. Even when I delete the model it reference this model. I have already tried makemigrations which works but when I run migrate the error pops up and the data is not altered.